# Which WordPress hook fires after save all post data and post meta?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook, cmb2

I have a custom post type crm, and i need to send a mail after each crm saved or updated. i user cmb2 for some custom meta like subject, to users etc. I know the `save_post` hook fires after post save *(according to WordPress codex)* in my case when i call `save_post` with two parameters *(id and post)* the post does not contains update values. here is my code :

```
function send_mail_to_user($id, $post){
    $crm = $post;
    $user_email = array();
    if($crm->vc_all_vc == 'on'){
        $args = array('orderby' => 'display_name');
        $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
        $authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();
        if (!empty($authors)) {
            foreach ($authors as $author) {
                array_push($user_email , $author->user_email );
            }
        } 
    }
    else{
        $to_users = $crm->vc_users;
        $to_program = $crm->vc_program;
        $to_group = $crm->vc_group;
        $to_excode = $crm->vc_ex_code;
        foreach ($to_users as $key => $value) {
            $user_data = get_userdata($value);
            array_push($user_email, $user_data->user_email);
        }
        foreach ($to_program as $key => $value) {
            $users = get_users( array('meta_key'     => 'programs'  ) );
            if($users){ 
                foreach ($users as $index => $data) {
                    if(in_array($value , explode('#', $data->programs))){
                        if(! in_array($data->user_email, $user_email)  )
                        {
                            array_push($user_email, $data->user_email);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        foreach($to_group as $group) {
            $term = get_term_by('slug', esc_attr($group), 'user-group');
            $user_ids = get_objects_in_term($term->term_id, 'user-group');
            foreach($user_ids as $user_id){
                $fc_user = get_userdata($user_id);
                if(! in_array($fc_user->user_email, $user_email)  )
                {
                    array_push($user_email, $fc_user->user_email);
                }
            }   
        }
        foreach($to_excode as $codes) {
            $value = explode('*',$codes)[1];
            $users = get_users( array('meta_key'     => 'programs'  ) );
            if($users){ 
                foreach ($users as $index => $data) {
                    if(in_array($value , explode('#', $data->programs))){
                        if(! in_array($data->user_email, $user_email)  )
                        {
                            array_push($user_email, $data->user_email);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    foreach($user_email as $index => $email){
        $to      = $email;
        $subject = $crm->vc_subject;
        $body    = $crm->post_content;
        $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        );
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'send_mail_to_user', 10, 2 );
```

And i also try `publish_post` hook , that works fine when new post created but when updated it works same. I have tried `edit_post` and `post_updated` hook also, but i never be able to retrieve my update data.

So how can i solve it? which action hook will give me all the new data? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: My work around for this has been to actually schedule a cron job to check the post meta about 10 seconds after the post has been updated. I have yet to find a hook that I can use that will consistently give me the post object with the updated meta, same problem as yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `post_updated` and use `$post_after` object.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated

Comment: Not working for me, it give the update post title and post_content but not update post meta

Comment: In this context `$post_after` is an instance of `WP_Post` class, so it does not include custom post meta.
Use `$meta  = get_post_meta($crm->ID);` in your function to get all post meta fields.

Comment: Yeah, i already done that, but the problem is the `meta value` i got is not the update one, probably cmb2 update `meta values` after   `post_updated` fires. I am only guessing that.

Comment: Good observation. Try searching the plugin files for `add_action` string, find out what hook it is using to save post meta data, then update your hook with a lower priority. Your function should run after the plugin saves the meta values and hopefully you will get the updated data.

Comment: If you are using Advanced Custum Fields (ACF), the regular WP hooks (including newer ones like rest_after_insert_{$this->post_type} mentioned in pippas answer) won't work, you have to use the ACF hook 'acf/save_post' https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/

Comment: A `wp_after_insert_post` hook is available since version 5.6. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71773904/1435770

Answer (score 8):

You can use something like this,

```
function your_custom_function($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key='', $meta_value='') {
    if($meta_key=='_edit_lock') {
        // if post meta is updated
    }
}
add_action('updated_post_meta', 'your_custom_function', 10, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! This is what I was looking for as the other actions/filters are firing multiple times.

Comment: Since from version 5.6 a `wp_after_insert_post` hook is available. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71773904/1435770

Answer (score 5):

This might be a bit old but just wanted to give an update since from version 5.6.0 a new hook is available. The hook is `wp_after_insert_post` and you can find more information [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_after_insert_post/) . This hook is triggered after a post is created or updated and all of its terms and meta are updated. You can find an example below:

```
add_action( 'wp_after_insert_post', 'send_mail_to_user', 90, 4 );

/**
 * Callback to: 'wp_after_insert_post'
 * Fires once a post, its terms and meta data has been saved
 * @param int     $post_id Post ID.
 * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
 * @param bool    $update  Whether this is an existing post being updated.
 * @param null|WP_Post $post_before Null for new posts, the WP_Post object prior to the update for updated posts.
 *
 */
public static function sync_product_registrations_on_update( $post_id, $post, $update, $post_before ) {

    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type ) {
        //Only to process the below when post type is 'post' else return
        return;
    }

    if ( ! in_array( $post->post_status, [ 'private', 'publish' ] ) ) {
        //To only process when status is private or publish
        return;
    }

    //The rest of your code goes here


}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use this `save_post` hook with your function. change your hook priority to 100 it will give you updated post

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'send_mail_to_user', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: Yeah it gives me update data, for the post only not post meta.

Comment: This not work for post meta data. If you get post meta in the function fired by this action you will get OLD meta data, because it is fired before post meta has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rest_after_insert_{$this->post_type}` hook (where `$this->post_type` is replaced with the post type, eg 'post' or 'myposttype').

Thanks to Florian Brinkmann for [this link](https://florianbrinkmann.com/en/metadata-post-update-block-editor-5744/).

```
add_action('rest_after_insert_myposttype', 'myfunction', 10, 3);

function myfunction($post, $request, $creating) {
   // $creating is TRUE if the post is created for the first time,
   // false if it's an update

   //  ...
}
```

[See also here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_after_insert_this-post_type/).

Comment: Won't this fail if REST is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Some workaround is to use $_POST['meta_field'] with sanitation:

```
$to_users = $_POST['vc_users'];
$to_program = $_POST['vc_program'];
$to_group = $_POST['vc_group'];
$to_excode = $_POST['vc_ex_code'];

$to_users = sanitize_text_field($to_users);
$to_program = sanitize_text_field($to_program);
$to_group = sanitize_text_field($to_group);
$to_excode = sanitize_text_field($to_excode);
```

Pay attention to the field names, using ACF will make you use the field key.

**This problem is more complicated than seems on first sight:**

Our ['post_updated' hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/) is running before post is updated, so every attempt for getting meta data will result with the previous data. Also, Wordpress (v5.7.2) doesn't seem to have a hook for after a post was saved.

Also, ['save_post' hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) is very complicated because it runs for every post saved or created including revisions and the $update boolean is still not reliable enough.

Comment: Seems like using $_POST  is the only way to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct and simpler answer is to use the `wp_insert_post` action.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/

> An important distinction of wp_insert_post action is that it is fired
> after update_post_meta has been called.

There are 3 parameters available - the $update flag tells you if this is a new or updated post.

```
do_action( 'wp_insert_post', int $post_ID, WP_Post $post, bool $update )
```

So - to implement your code after all post meta has been updated, use something like this:

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'run_after_post_updated', 10, 3);    
function run_after_post_updated($post_ID, $post, $update ) {
   //  ...
}
```

Comment: A `wp_after_insert_post` hook is available since version 5.6. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71773904/1435770

Comment: Sure - and it's in the same position as wp_insert_post except that wp_after_insert_post may not fire, depending on parameters passed to the function wp_insert_post. See https://i.imgur.com/Ou74dKy.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the save_post action wih a higher priority so that your function is called afer all meta data has been saved.

```
add_action( 'save_post',  'action_woocommerce_update_product', 20, 3 );
Here I have used higher priority 20
```